# Video.js CDN for Android (Responsive)

Tags: android, responsive, video.js

Just started trying to use VideoJS for a new website targeting mobile users.  On the Getting Started page under Video.JS CDN it gives code to try out (see https://videojs.com/getting-started).  What I am looking for is a version of this that will make the video responsive on Androids and IOS so that it fills the container but maintains its aspect ratio.  Using the code below from Getting Started with a 1280 x 720 video when it first loads it is too big for the screen.  But (weirdly) click full-screen and it is perfect.
I'm guessing this code must be available as VideoJS says it is for Androids/IOS and is responsive, but can't find it :(  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vjs-fluid` class which will fill the width of the container while maintaining aspect ratio.

https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-layout.html

Comment: That's most helpful misterben.  And works now!  But I am now having a problem with using an IFrame to embed the video.  For some reason when using an IFrame the Full Screen Button on the player is not working.  Would you know of an IFrame Generator that is both Responsive but also will allow the VideoJS player to have a functioning Full Screen Button?  Any help hugely appreciated.

Comment: Found it.  Just added 'allowfullscreen' and all good.  Thanks again :)